# Angular 4 <router-outlet> prints out content twice after clicking back/forward button

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2, angular-router

I'm experiencing a very strange interaction with angular v4.2.4 `<router-outlet>`. As shown below, I have two views: `listing` view and `details` view. When I click on the details button, I route to the `details` view. The `listing` and the `details` view are side by side. If I click the browser's back button, the `details` view reminds there and the `listing` view duplicates.

The goal is for the property listing card to disappear when the user clicks on the details button.

### / - on the home page

[image: home page]

### /details - after a user clicks on the details button on the rental listing card

[image: after clicking on details button]

## / - user clicks on the brower's back. You can see the content has duplicated.

[image: returned back to home with dup content]

### app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { MatToolbarModule, MatCardModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule} from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PropertyComponent } from './property/property.component';
import { PropertyService } from './property/property.service';
import { ListingComponent } from './property/listing/listing.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './property/listing/details/details.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PropertyComponent,
        ListingComponent,
        DetailsComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: '---'
        })
    ],
    providers: [PropertyService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  host: { 'class': 'rental__root' }
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

### app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PropertyComponent } from './property/property.component';
import { ListingComponent } from './property/listing/listing.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './property/listing/details/details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: PropertyComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ListingComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'details',
                component: DetailsComponent
            }
        ]
    }
    //{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

### app.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="rental__toolbar mat-elevation-z6">
    <span>Rentals</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<main role="main" fxLayout>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

### property.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-property',
    templateUrl: './property.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./property.component.scss'],
    host: { 'class': 'property' }
})
export class PropertyComponent implements OnInit {
    lat: number = 39.9281788;
    lng: number = -75.16583880000002;
    zoom: number = 16;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

### property.component.html

```
<div fxFlex="70" fxLayout fxFill>
    <agm-map class="property__map" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
</div>
<div class="property__sidenav mat-elevation-z10" fxFlex="30" fxLayout fxFill>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

### listing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PropertyService } from '../property.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-listing',
    templateUrl: './listing.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./listing.component.scss']
})
export class ListingComponent implements OnInit {

    properties: any;

    constructor(
        private propertyService: PropertyService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.propertyService.getProperty().subscribe(properties => {
            this.properties = properties;
            console.log(this.properties)
        });
    }

}
```

### listing.component.html

```
<mat-card class="listing" *ngFor="let property of properties.properties">
    <div class="listing__image">
        <img class="listing__image-background" mat-card-image src="" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
    </div>
    <!--<div class="listing__image">
        <div class="listing__image-background" [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ property.image[0].url +')'"></div>
    </div>-->
    <mat-card-title>
        {{property.type}} &mdash;
        {{property.price}} / mo.
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>
        {{property.address.street}}
        {{property.address.city}}
        {{property.address.state}}
    </mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-list fxLayout>
            <mat-list-item fxFlex="20">
                <mat-icon matListIcon>hotel</mat-icon>
                <h4 class="listing__icon-title" matLine>{{property.bed}} beds</h4>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item fxFlex="20">
                <mat-icon matListIcon>hot_tub</mat-icon>
                <h4 class="listing__icon-title" matLine>{{property.bath}} bath</h4>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item fxFlex="20">
                <mat-icon matListIcon>view_compact</mat-icon>
                <h4 class="listing__icon-title" matLine>{{property.sqft}} sqft.</h4>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item fxFlex>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>directions_walk</mat-icon>
                <h4 class="listing__icon-title" matLine>{{property.walkscore}} (Walker's Paradise)</h4>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
        <p>{{property.description.short}}</p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/details">DETAILS</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

### details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.sass']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

### details.component.html

```
<p>
  details works!
</p>
```

Comment: can you add ur component constructor, like app.component.ts

Comment: @TheophilusOmoregbee I sure can! I updated the question. I added all component constructors and html pages

Comment: This normally happens when the DOM fails to render properly from the Angular compiler at runtime, and isn't related to the router itself. There is likely an error occurring (have you checked dev console?). Similar causes are directive data isn't loading properly, async data isn't available, etc. DOM can't be rendered, and so the compiler is breaking at runtime.

Comment: In your listing component you should add implements OnDestroy and then in ngOnDestroy unsubscribe from your subscription. You could be subscribing twice to the property service and getting duplicate entries because of it. If console.log(this.properties) is getting called twice this is likely the case.

Comment: Looked through, and what Woot says is the most likely cause.

Comment: You're both right! Thank you!